# Potential issues with uploading copyrighted material to TurnItIn?

Tags: ethics, plagiarism

My university uses [TurnItIn](http://turnitin.com/) to check student's work for plagiarism and collusion. I think the underlying TurnItIn database includes both submitted work and material it has found by crawling the web, but not material behind pay walls. One major issue with TurnItIn, and presumably all plagiarism detection software, is that it can only compare submitted work to material which is in the database. This means that TurnItIn either misses when students copy from textbooks which are behind a pay wall or matches other sources which have plagiarised the textbook.

My department's academic misconduct committee is thinking about seeding the TurnItIn database with the textbook chapters that are most often used by the students by submitting a number of "assignments" that are copies of the textbook chapters. This would require an individual member(s) of staff to submit assignments that contained copied copyright material. Is it possible that this could get the staff member in trouble in the future? We were thinking about adding something like:

> The following submission is intended to seed the TurnItIn database and is an exact copy of FULL REFERENCE.

Would this work, or would TurnItIn realize that it is being given copyrighted material and purge it from its database?

Comment: I'd be less concerned about TurnItIn purging it than about the copyright holder suing the pants off you. You'd probably have to discuss this with your institution's lawyers.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I agree, but I wouldn't be the one making money off it, TurnItIn would be, so I think they would be more at risk.

Comment: Use should check with the folks at Turnitin, but I believe that it makes use of the Crossref database which includes published materials (journals, conference proceedings and books) from most commercial publishers.  See http://www.crossref.org/

Comment: Do you hold the copyright in the textbooks in question or have a license that allows you to submit a *copy* of their work? If not, don't do it. It's a copyright violation.

Comment: @BillBarth it is possibly, probably probably, a copyright violation but since any illegal copies in my possession will be destroyed immediately, I won't make a profit, and TurnItIn would be causing the financial losses (if any), I am not sure it matters.

Comment: @BrianBorchers TurnItIn includes some books, but it misses many of our core textbooks.

Comment: @StrongBad, profit has only a small part to do with it. If you are trying to make a fair use argument in the US, that's one prong (market for the work), but it's not everything. Copyright law allows the holder to control distribution of copies, and by sending it to TurnItIn, you are distributing a copy without permission. Don't open yourself to suit. Fair use is a defense to suit, not a get out of jail free card. You still might have to go to court to defend a suit, which is expensive. Just don't do it.

Comment: @BillBarth You are right, they _can_ sue. However, the OP is in the UK which is not nearly litigious as the US. Add to this the fact that the publisher would be unlikely to know it was posted (TurnItIn does not make it publicly available) and the fact that it is literally distributing a single copy, I believe the downside is extremely limited.

Comment: @earthling, first, the textbook publisher may be in the US and can sue the uploader there instead of where they live. Second, copyright infringement is against civil law (i.e. not a crime at this scale) and statutory damages are provided for infringement. Are you suggesting that it is ethical for faculty to break the law to catch students cheating? That doesn't pass the sniff test. OP might be only making one copy, but it's still probably wrong. Is that the kind of ethics we want to demonstrate to our students in our zeal to catch their plagiarism?

Comment: @BillBarth I do not think it is unethical. The legal side is unclear but I remain convinced the risk to the school and the OP is extremely small. Of course, they decide and live with the benefits and consequences.

Comment: @earthlng, so your ethics say, if the legal case is unclear, just do what you want? I think erring on the side of caution here is the more ethical approach. OP doesn't appear to have consulted with their university's legal department for an opinion. I wouldn't go further without doing so. Finally, I think the easiest and best thing to do is to ask the *publisher* to submit the textbook to TurnItIn.

Comment: _so your ethics say, if the legal case is unclear, just do what you want?_ — Oh, come on.  Not basing your ethics on existing law doesn't mean you don't have any.

Comment: @BillBarth My ethics do not say that. I believe that something can be unethical and legal but something else can be ethical and illegal. Legality and ethics do not define each other. And, yes, I agree with your suggestion, the publisher doing that would help everyone.

Comment: @JeffE, I do not accuse earthing of having *no* ethics, so don't be so dramatic. Ethics isn't usually about making risk tradeoffs. It's usually about doing the "right" thing in the face of things that you believe "ought" to be different. Taking someone else's property and giving it to another in order to make one's own life easier without bothering to ask the original owner even if you might win a court battle over it later is definitely unethical in my book. I think OP should ask the publisher to submit and *suck it up* and deal with it if they won't. Catching cheaters is not more important.

Comment: I fail to see the difference between uploading copyrighted material to Turnitin, and uploading students submissions, some of which may content copyrighted text. In fact the reason to upload students works to Turnitin is that they are suspected of containing copyrighted works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment, but I also acknowledge that only someone from TurnItIn could categorically answer this.

Since TurnItIn does not provide access to source material (other than small sections which actually match the submitted paper), I do not see how it could be a copyright issue. I get matches all the time from papers submitted to other schools, yet, TurnItIn does not allow me to see that paper.

Additionally, much of the content within TurnItIn is under copyright (blogs and others) and they do not purge it, further implying that they would not have a problem with your plan.

All that said, unless the content is quite new, or changed regularly, as soon as one student includes content, any other student including that same content will trigger a flag for you.

So, I do not believe your plan will have any problem but I am also not sure you need to worry about it unless you have a special set of texts you believe other students around the world will not have access to.

Comment: Our academic misconduct policy says we need to find the original source. This means that when an assignment matches a student's paper at another university, which we cannot access, then we need to find the original source. We think this would help us get back to the original source.

Comment: @StrongBad Then I think it **will** solve your problem.

Comment: This answer is very wrong with respect to whether the proposed actions would raise any copyright issues. Providing TurnItIn with *copies* of any copyright-protected works for which the submitter has neither the copyright nor a permissive license is presumptively a copyright violation. There have been cases holding that submitting student works does not violate the students' copyrights, but I think the issue is still unclear when it comes to you submitting a textbook owned by someone else. Furthermore such disclaimer statements have NO VALUE in defense against copyright infringement suits.

Comment: @BillBarth the disclaimer wasn't for copyright protection, but rather for professional misconduct protection (to the extent that copyright infringement is not professional misconduct, or something like that).

Comment: @StrongBad, such disclaimers may or may not have any value to you in front of a misconduct tribunal. I wouldn't given them much weight.

Comment: @BillBarth Can you provide some evidence of the cases you mentioned? I know LOTS of people have problems with turnitin but I am unfamiliar with anyone winning a case for copyright infringement and would like to see the details of the ruling(s).

Comment: @earthling, Google "turnitin copyright issues" and find [this](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20080325/005954642.shtml) 2008 article on TechDirt. Etc.

Comment: @BillBarth Since the link said it was not copyright infringement, i think tje jury is still out. I believe the issue is that Turnitin is not publishing that content or making it available to others. However, I do agree that this can vary by country just like dl'ing movie torrents is ok in some countries if nobody is paying.

Comment: @earthling, TurnItIn might be off the hook when it comes to student-produced content, but there's nothing in evidence that would clear an uploader of textbook.

Comment: @BillBarth Perhaps, but the burden of proof would fall on the accusor. That's why I would like to see a case where your theory is tested.

Comment: @earthling, OP might become the first if they follow their current proposed course of action. Why don't *you* upload a textbook, call the publisher, and dare them to sue you? Then we'll know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

My guesstimate is that this at least in Germany (where I some little knowledge about copyright) this would not be covered by any copyright exception.

But, why not go the official way and ask the publisher? 
Or ask turnitin to ask the publisher?

Answer (score 0):

Copyright refers to the right to make a copy, so your scheme violates US copyright law, and that's that as far as the ethical question is concerned. Whether the author / publisher could recover damages from you (or whoever the copier is) depends on strategic questions such as the depth of your pockets. Acting as an agent for a university, the pockets could be pretty deep. Making a profit is not part of the definition of copyright violation. It could also expose Turnitin to legal action by the copyright holder, which means they could have a cause of action against you. OTOH they may realize that it's unlikely that a publisher would actually bother.

Comment: Copyright is a legal condition, not an ethical one.

Comment: It's a legal recognition of a property right, and respect / violation for rights is an ethical question.

Comment: The boundaries of property rights are an ethical question that is independent of the law.

Comment: @JeffE, on the contrary and as noted here, exposing a third party to risk of harm without their informed consent is generally considered unethical. If that harm is a lawsuit, then that intertwines questions of ethics and questions of law. They are not always independent.