# Is it wise to upload all the publshed research works to the Standard Paper Repository of Turnitin?

Tags: plagiarism

My organization is using Turnitin software and I am the Administrator. Will it be a wise decision to upload all our published research works to the Standard Paper Repository of the software in order to avoid plagiarising of them in the future?

Comment: Related https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38385/potential-issues-with-uploading-copyrighted-material-to-turnitin

Answer (score 3):

You should get legal advice regarding the consequences, and the intellectual property, [legal](https://cccc.ncte.org/cccc/committees/ip/plagiarismdetection) or ethical issues that may arise from uploading your research, or student work, to their database.

The [Turnitin blog](https://www.turnitin.com/blog/a-similarity-report-to-be-proud-of) seems to indicate that whatever documents you upload to the Standard Paper Repository will be further used (capitalized) to serve other customers:

> Opting to store papers in the standard paper repository contributes to report accuracy around the world; this is because papers submitted to your assignment will be added to our global database, allowing future submissions to any institution to match against your students' papers.

Several concerns have surfaced about these practices:

1. ["Turnitin: If you're a student, all your intellectual property might belong to us"](https://www.zdnet.com/article/turnitin-if-youre-a-student-all-your-intellectual-property-might-belong-to-us/?p=8762&page=2)
2. ["Anti Turnitin manifesto calls for resistance to some technology"](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2017/06/19/anti-turnitin-manifesto-calls-resistance-some-technology-digital-age)
3. [et cetera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnitin#Reception)...